# Django EmbeddedField raises ValidationError because of renamed field

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, djongo

I've got a Django application with `djongo` as a database driver. The models are:

```py
class Blog(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column="Name")
    tagline = models.TextField()

class Entry(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    blog = models.EmbeddedField(
        model_container=Blog
    )
```

When I run this application, I got an error:

```
File "\.venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\models\fields.py", line 125, in _validate_container
    raise ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['Field "m.Blog.name"  of model container:"<class \'project.m.models.Blog\'>" cannot be named as "name", different from column name "Name"']
```

I want to keep the name of the field `name` in my model and database different because the database already exists, and I can't change it. The database uses camelCase for naming fields, whereas in the application, I want to use snake_case.

How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is due to Djongo trying to validate the field `name` as in the model and `Name` as created in the database.
You can specify for Djongo to not validate the fields of the model container by setting `validate=False` in the `EmbeddedField`.
Modify your Entry model as:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    blog = models.EmbeddedField(
        model_container=Blog, validate=False
    )
```

This should fix your error.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not fix the error.

Comment: Did you run the migration commands afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column="BlogName")
    tagline = models.TextField()
```

or this

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    BlogName = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column="name")
    tagline = models.TextField()
```

When you use the "db_colum" parameter, you must choose a different name, even if it is lowercase or uppercase

Answer (score 1):

you might need to do `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `db_column` instead of `bd_column` so:

```py
class Blog(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column="Name")
    tagline = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Yes, I mistyped the param name. Edited my question. There is another reason for the error